# FooterWrap breaking box

Tags: css, wordpress, footer

What's up with my Footer CSS ?

Using the Web Dev toolbar in Firefox I can see that it's got  a box and it seems to be pushing it all down to the next line - no padding or margins that I can see..

I'm sure it's an easy fix - if someone could point out what's up that would be ace!

Thanks guys!

---

Website is here for [Love Jungle Clothing Brand](http://www.lovejungle.com)

Here is the code:

```
/****** Footer *****/
/*new div Neil */


#footerwrap
{width: 100%;
margin: 0 auto;
text-align:left;
height:40px;
background-color:#000;
clear:both;
margin-top:10px;
overflow:hidden;
z-index:1000;
}




/*new div container Neil */
#footer {
    width: 990px;
    height:60px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding-top:10px;
    background-color:#000;
    clear:both;
    text-align:center;
    z-index:1000;
}


#footer ul {
    padding: 0px 0 0 0;
    margin: 0 0 0 0px;
    list-style-type: none;
}
#footer li {
    float: right;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: inline;
}




#footerLeft ul {
    padding: 0px 0 0 0;
    margin: 0 0 0 0px;
    list-style-type: none;
}
#footerLeft li {
    float: left;

}


#footer a {

    display: block;
    height: 40px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    display: inline;
    text-decoration:none;
    text-align:center;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 90%;
white-space:nowrap;
    margin:0 auto;
        z-index:1000;


}



#footerwrap a {

    display: block;
    color:#fff;
    height: 20px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    padding-right:40px;
    margin:0 auto;
        z-index:1000;

}




/****** Footer *****/
/*new div Neil */


#footerwrap
{width: 100%;
margin: 0 auto;
text-align:left;
height:40px;
background-color:#000;
clear:both;
margin-top:10px;
overflow:hidden;
z-index:1000;
}




/*new div container Neil */
#footer {
    width: 990px;
    height:60px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding-top:10px;
    background-color:#000;
    clear:both;
    text-align:center;
    z-index:1000;
}


#footer ul {
    padding: 0px 0 0 0;
    margin: 0 0 0 0px;
    list-style-type: none;
}
#footer li {
    float: right;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: inline;
}




#footerLeft ul {
    padding: 0px 0 0 0;
    margin: 0 0 0 0px;
    list-style-type: none;
}
#footerLeft li {
    float: left;

}


#footer a {

    display: block;
    height: 40px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    display: inline;
    text-decoration:none;
    text-align:center;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 90%;
white-space:nowrap;
    margin:0 auto;
        z-index:1000;


}



#footerwrap a {

    display: block;
    color:#fff;
    height: 20px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    padding-right:40px;
    margin:0 auto;
        z-index:1000;

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you trying to use the "footer stick" method?  Or do you just want to have the text content sort of vertically centered.  If the latter, try this:

Look in your footer file, you have the following html:

```
<div id="footerwrap"> 
   <div id="footer">
      <div id="footerLeft">
      <a href="/about/"></a><li><a href="/about/">Made in Australia</a></li>
      </div>

<ul>
<span>
<center>
         <li><a href="/store/">Store</a></li>
         <li><a href="/about">About</a></li>
         <li><a href="/press">Press</a></li>
         <li><a href="/stockists">Stockists</a></li>
         <li><a href="/contact"><span>Contact</span></a></li>
</center>
</span>
</ul>

    </div>
</div>
```

This line:  **`<a href="/about/"></a><li><a href="/about/">Made in Australia</a></li>`** needs to be removed.

If you want more info on the footer-stick method check out http://bonrouge.com/~home

Comment: Sorry - I should have been clearer. 

Currently there is text on the right of the footer "Store, about, press, stockists, Contact" 

I want to place text on the left of the footer also "Made In Australia" 

The way it is set up now though is forcing it to push down into the footer chrome and you can't read it. 

Should the footer be set up a different way?

The Footer-stick is there as well to make the black wrap stick to the bottom of the page.. 

Hope that makes sense?

Comment: ok, so I changed the code to be 

<li><a href="/about/">Made in Australia</a></li>

And it has centered the text vertically like I wanted - but now the footer had white beneath it - i'll have to look over the footerstick method I guess?